# Alert Mainthread from retrofit when data is ready

Tags: android, multithreading, retrofit

I had a retrofit request, when I get data in onResponse,
I did multiples insert in textviews which I called heavy work in the code above, I get the result from OnReponse if there's one, else I get result from database, so the problem I had the same code in OnResponse and OnFailure, so there's any way to put my heavy work outside retrofit, and wait the response to get just one result from OnResponse or OnFailure ??

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<Dashboard>() {
                     @Override
                     public void onResponse(Call<Dashboard> call, Response<Dashboard> response) {

                         realm.beginTransaction();
                         dashboard = realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(response.body());
                         realm.commitTransaction();

                         // heavy work : insert in data in multiple text views


                     }

                     @Override
                     public void onFailure(Call<Dashboard> call, Throwable t) {
                         Log.e("error ", "" + t.getMessage());

                         dashboard = realm.where(Dashboard.class).findFirst();
                         // heavy work : insert in data in multiple text views
                     }
                 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..
First Create an interface ..Let's call it OKCallback.

```
public interface OKCallback {
void onSuccess(String result);

void onFailure(String result);
```

}

Then in your method that launches the retrofit request, pass final OKCallback okCallback like this..

```
 public void NetworkCall(final OKCallback okCallback){

...........
call.enqueue(new Callback<Dashboard>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Dashboard> call, Response<Dashboard> response) {

                realm.beginTransaction();
                dashboard = realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(response.body());
                realm.commitTransaction();

               // heavy work : insert in data in multiple text views
               okCallback.onSuccess(parcel);

}
```

Finally simply (ActivityX implements OKCallback) in any class or activity and you should be able to do your heavy work there..You can also wrap your data in the onSuccess methods with a Handler as shown.

```
 @Override
public void onSuccess(String result) {
    Handler handler = new Handler(ActivityX.this.getMainLooper());

    //process result and
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            //heavy work done here will run on UI thread
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change it like this

```
//create a interface
    public interface ConfirmationCallback {
          void onSuccess(YourResponseClass value);
          void onError();
    }

    //call this method from your class
    yourApiCall(new ConfirmationCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(YourResponseClass value) {
                    realm.beginTransaction();
                    dashboard = realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(value);
                    realm.commitTransaction();
                    // heavy work : insert in data in multiple text views
                }

                @Override
                public void onError() {
                    dashboard = realm.where(Dashboard.class).findFirst();
                    // heavy work : insert in data in multiple text views
                }
            });


         public void yourApiCall(final ConfirmationCallback confirmationCallback){
            call.enqueue(new Callback<Dashboard>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Dashboard> call, Response<Dashboard> response) {
                   confirmationCallback.onSuccess(response.body());
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Dashboard> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.e("error ", "" + t.getMessage());
                    confirmationCallback.onError();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: thank's for the response, but the heavy work still twice !

Comment: @stanly now check this answer

Answer (score 0):

You can make an interface and get call back on main thread or after getting response of api call in onSuccess() or in onfailure() start a new AsynTask and process the request in background.